# How to update an existing excel spreadsheet with data from dataframe

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I need to update an existing excel spreadsheet with data from dataframe 'CF'. I try this code but nothing happens and I don't get an error. Could you suggest what could be wrong?

```
import openpyxl as ox
def update_spreadsheet(path : str ='/a123.xlsx', _df = CF, starcol : int = 1, startrow : int = 1, sheet_name : str ="TDSheet"):
    wb = ox.load_workbook(path)
    for ir in range(0, len(_df)):
        for ic in range(0, len(_df.iloc[ir])):
            wb[sheet_name].cell(startrow + ir, starcol + ic).value = _df.iloc[ir][ic]
    wb.save(path)
```

Comment: Try looking at [update excel sheet in pandas Code Example](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/update+excel+sheet+in+pandas).

Comment: Is this complete code? Try using `openpyxl.utils.datafram_to_rows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you did not see any response/error is because you created a function, but did not call it. I have updated the function code and called it to update a sheet with some random data. Let me know if you face any issues.

**Code**

```
import openpyxl as ox
import numpy as np
CF = pd.DataFrame() # Had to define this as you kept CF as default. But, would suggest you don't have _df=CF, but rather just _df

def update_spreadsheet(path:str ='/a123.xlsx', _df=CF, startcol:int=1, startrow:int=1, sheet_name:str ="TDSheet"):
    wb = ox.load_workbook(path)
    ws=wb[sheet_name]
    for row in range(0, _df.shape[0]): #For each row in the dataframe
        for col in range(0, _df.shape[1]): #For each column in the dataframe
            ws.cell(row = startrow + row, column = startcol + col).value = _df.iat[row, col]
    wb.save(path)

#Dummy data for CF
CF = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(10, 3)))

#Call the defined function
update_spreadsheet('./a123.xlsx', CF, 3, 20, 'Sheet1') #Write to sheet1 starting from row 20 and column 3 / column C
```

Comment: You're right, the problem was that I didn't call the function. Thank you very much now everything is working well. Both versions of the code are working.

Comment: It turns out the cycle function writes data to an existing excel sheet about 30 times longer than it takes to write data to a new file.

Comment: Glad to hear... Good Luck !!